# Multithreading in professional projects

Tags: multithreading

To better understand concurrent computing, I would like to know the exact examples of multithreading in projects. Could you list some examples that you came across and describe what responsibilities each thread has?

Please be patient. I'm still learning. :-)

Comment: can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780024/what-is-multithreading?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen examples where several threads are used for different purposes: one for handling audit logging, one for handling messaging with external systems, one for the applicative routine (where the actual transaction happens). This is not however a concurrent systems per se, as the threads are handling separate tasks.

One can use threads to divide I/O heavy work: imagine an application processing a lot of files. The basic approach would be to process files one after the other, but the process would be waiting for I/O for every file that is processed. Using a pool of threads and assiging 1 file to each thread can allow the process to keep running: some threads are waiting for I/O, but the others can still keep doing their job. Again, this approach is non-concurrent, as long as you don't process the same file on 2 different threads (one writing to the file and the other one reading, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Trackers running concurrently is commonly done with threading.

Comment: What do you mean saying 'Multiple Tracker'? Could you give some example? Sorry, I'm newbie :-(

Comment: Sure, say you have a video of people in a crowd. You want to track(have the computer follow) these people. You COULD just do this all in one program but that would be REALLY slow because you would have to do this person by person. With threading, you can have each of these trackers running separately and it is much FASTER. Additionally, threading is used in calculations where you need to do a lot of things(that DONT HAVE TO BE SEQUENTIAL), then your threads can work on the same problem together. This also makes these calculations faster